# How to assign result of sed to variable

Tags: bash, shell-script, sed, environment-variables, bash-script

Below is a complete copy of a demo I'm using to to figure out to get the `sed` command to get rid of the spaces in a persons name, and compress it down to not have spaces.

Once this is done, I want to assign it to the variable `comp` then I can re-use it later on in the script. Here I am just trying to `echo` it to the stdout so I can see it worked.

If I run the script and enter my name as `Ronald McDonald` the result I get returned is `RonaldMcDonald}` with that curly brace on the end of his name, or whatever I type in.

How do I get it to work, so that the result doesn't append the `}` to the back of the assigned text.

```
#!/bin/bash

function readName {
    echo "Enter your full name:"
    read fullName
    clear
}    # end readName

function cmprsName {
    comp={ echo "$fullName" } | sed 's/ //g'
}    # end cmprsName

function sayItNow {
    echo $comp
}    # end sayItNow

function allTogether {
    readName
    cmprsName
    sayItNow
}    #end allTogether

case $1 in
        -h | --help )           allTogether
                                exit
                                ;;
        * )                     echo "$0 -h"
                                exit 1
esac
```

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You have to use command substitution for this, i.e. instead of

```
comp={ echo "$fullName" } | sed 's/ //g'
```

something like

```
comp=$(echo "$fullName"  | sed 's/ //g')
```

or

```
comp=`echo "$fullName"  | sed 's/ //g'`
```

Comment: It should perhaps be noted that the `$(..)` syntax is preferred to the older `\`..\`` syntax for reasons of readability and nesting.