# Using sed command returned to variable

Tags: bash, sed

I'm trying to use `sed` to remove some characters and return the result to a variable. But I can't seem to get it to work. Here's what i've tried and the corresponding errors I get.

```
PROJECT_DB_NAME=`sed -i "${var}"'s/[^a-zA-Z]//g'`
```

**Error** *sed: -i may not be used with stdin*

```
PROJECT_DB_NAME=`"$var" | sed -n 's/[^a-zA-Z]//g'`
```

**Error** *domain.com: command not found*

I've found lots of example but none do exactly what I want to do and I'm a bit of a bash noob. 
Thanks

Comment: Have you tried removing the `-i` option? Are you using sed to process a file, or to process the output of some other command?

Comment: Your question is not clear, are you trying to set the variable to the return value of sed or the output of sed ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need `sed` to remove non-alphabetic characters from the value of a variable in `bash`.  A simple variable substitution will do the same thing:

```
PROJECT_DB_NAME=${var//[![:alpha:]]}
```

If you want to use `[!a-zA-Z]` in place of `[![:alpha:]`, then that is of course also possible.

If you really want to use an external command for removing these characters, use the more light-weight `tr` rather than `sed`.  The task of `tr` is exactly to do things like these (single character transliterations).

```
PROJECT_DB_NAME=$( tr -dc '[:alpha:]' <<<"$var" )
```

or,

```
PROJECT_DB_NAME=$( printf '%s\n' "$var" | tr -dc '[:alpha:]' )
```

See the manual for the `tr` command.

Note that using `echo` may alter the contents of the variable before `sed` sees it.  See the question "[Why is printf better than echo?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/65803)".

---

Your first piece of code,

```
PROJECT_DB_NAME=`sed -i "${var}"'s/[^a-zA-Z]//g'`
```

would run `sed` without a filename.  This makes `sed` assume that data is arriving over standard input.  The `-i` option, as the error message says, can't be used with standard input.  Also, you prepend the `sed` code with the value of the variable.  This would make the variable's value be interpreted as `sed` editing commands.

Your second piece of code,

```
PROJECT_DB_NAME=`"$var" | sed -n 's/[^a-zA-Z]//g'`
```

This tries to run `"$var"` as a command on the left hand side of the pipeline.  Also, you use `sed -n` which will cause `sed` to *not* output the modified data by default.

Comment: Awesome. Thank you for the explanation.

Answer (score 1):

Ok I found the answer here: 
[How to assign result of sed to variable](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/93674/how-to-assign-result-of-sed-to-variable)

I had looked at that answer but implemented it wrong at my end. So here's what I ended up with:

`PROJECT_DB_NAME=$( echo "$var" | sed 's/[^a-zA-Z]//g')`